# Converge or Divergence extreme case

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The following convergence question came to my mind.  Consider the following infinite set of functions $f_{i}$
$f_{0} = n$
$f_{1} = n \cdot \log_2(n+2)$
$f_{2} = n \cdot \log_2(n+2) \cdot \log_2(\log_2(n+4))$
$f_{3} = n \cdot \log_2(n+2) \cdot \log_2(\log_2(n+4)) \cdot \log_2(\log_2(\log_2(n+16)))$
...

If I'm not mistaken, $\sum 1/f_{i}$ diverges for all i but the divergence gets slower and slower as i increases

My question is does $\sum 1/f_{\omega}$ converge or diverge and if it converges what does it converge to?

Comment: The pattern is ambiguous. I can guess that $f_4$ has  a term $n+128$ in it but I can just as logically guess that $f_4$ has a term $n+256$.

Comment: its the tetration sequence 2, 2^2, 2^2^2, 2^2^2^2...  so the next term is 2^(previous term) = 2^16 = 65536.  If you graph these functions with these terms you'll that the functions are approach a limit function which I'm calling $f_{\omega}$